# Can G-code scripts be run automatically on inserting an SD card when using Marlin Firmware?

Tags: marlin, g-code, firmware, scripts

When running [Marlin Firmware](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin), is it possible to run [G-code](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code) scripts/series of commands automatically when you insert the SD card?

---

I'm running Marlin on a 3D printer board using an ATmega 2560 based board with a reprap discount LCD controller with an SD card slot. I would like to do this without the need to add another computer/board, so native from the board running the Marlin Firmware.

Comment: Not quite the answer, but close: https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/wiki/Autostart.

Comment: Adding link to [Nikkoura's answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4256/how-can-i-add-auto-bed-leveling-before-print/6740#6740) and while that deals with power-on only, [this post](https://reprap.org/forum/read.php?415,833394) on the Marlin forum asks about purely insertion on a printer which is *already* powered on. [A reply](https://reprap.org/forum/read.php?415,833394,833489#msg-833489) was received and apparently it should be possible by making a code change in `ultralcd.ccp`

Comment: A feature request has been made on Marlin's GitHub, see [Can G-code scripts be run automatically on inserting an SD card when using Marlin Firmware?](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/11815)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not *entirely sure* if this is what you are after, or if it will work, but from  [this post](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/2891#issuecomment-180980733) on [Printing From SD Card when printer is turned On](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/2891)

> While an LCD controller is not needed for auto#.g to work, if you have an LCD controller you can use the `MENU_ADDAUTOSTART` option to add a menu command that will run the auto0.g, auto1.g, auto2.g whenever you want.

This (final) post ended up closing the thread so it appears to answer the OP's question - however, whether it will answer your question is another matter.

---

[This post](https://reprap.org/forum/read.php?415,833394), on the Marlin forum, replicates your question and asks about purely insertion of an SD card on a printer which is *already* powered on.

[A reply](https://reprap.org/forum/read.php?415,833394,833489#msg-833489) was received and apparently it should be possible by making a code change in `ultralcd.ccp`:

> It does not seem like an auto print, when inserting a SD-card, is to
> be found in the current program code of Marlin.
>
> You might consider making a feature request here: [[github.com](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues)]
>
> I do not think that it would require much work to implement a
> "card.autoprintfile()" function in Marlin. It seems to me that a call
> to such a function could happen at line 5172 right after:
>
> ```
> else
> LCD_MESSAGEPGM(MSG_SD_INSERTED);
> ```
>
> in the file `ultralcd.ccp`

A subsequent feature request has been made on Marlin's GitHub, see [[FR] Can G-code scripts be run automatically on inserting an SD card when using Marlin Firmware?](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/11815)

However, from [this reply](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/11815#issuecomment-420791259), it appears that a feature request is already pending:

> I'm not in favor of this as a general feature. We already have a
> feature request to be able to run custom G-code in response to various
> events, with SD card insertion being one of those events. Would that
> feature serve your needs?

However, as yet, I do not have a link to this other feature request. Will update as and when.

---

As an aside, in might be worth mentioning that the SDFat related code could be the place to code this in, see [if SD card removed, how to flag and restart?](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=360754.0), although after looking at the Marlin codebase, in particular [`SdFatUtils.cpp`](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/Marlin/SdFatUtil.cpp), this would appear to be a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you would like to achieve.

As @typo mentioned there is similar functionality which triggers at printer startup: https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/wiki/Autostart

I found in Marlin's source code that you can enable that autostart feature to be triggered from menu. Just enable `MENU_ADDAUTOSTART` in [Configuration_adv.h](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/Marlin/Configuration_adv.h).

If you really need a g-code that start after sd-card insert then you have to adjust the marlin source code on your own. I suggest to alter file [cardreader.cpp](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/Marlin/cardreader.cpp). There you have to trigger the autostart procedure after a sd-card is inserted.